# Unable to Update last_login field of Django in-built user

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Built in `User` model of django contains `last_login` field. I am updating `last_login` when user logouts from the website.

views.py:

```
def logout(request):
    template = loader.get_template('logout.html')
    print("I am Loging out... BYY", request.user.id)
    User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).update(last_login=timezone.now)
    auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))
```

I am getting Error on `User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).update(last_login=timezone.now)`
 which says `expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Note you can use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut to simplify the view: `return render(request, 'logout.html')`.

Comment: @Alasdair when I use `HttpResponse()` is it is expensive for system, Because Both do the same thing

Comment: The advantage of `render()` is that it simplifies the code because you can remove the `template = loader.get_template('logout.html')` line. The performance will similar for both.

Comment: @Alasdair Ok... I got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call the `timezone.now` method.

```
User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).update(last_login=timezone.now())
```